# Playing a file recorded with AVAudioRecorder on AVAudioPlayer

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

Right now I'm trying to play a .wav file that is first recorded with a `AVAudioRecorder`, and then playing this sound with a `AVAudioPlayer`. This seems simple enough, but i want the `AVAudioRecorder` PAUSED, not stopped. That is the problem, for some reason the `AVAudioPlayer` refuses to play a file that is opened in the recorder. So this works:

```
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
[recorder record];

*record for some time*

[recorder stop];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self copySoundFileURL] error:nil];
[player play];
```

But i want it to work when i call it like this:

```
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:settings error:&error];
[recorder record];

*record for some time*

[recorder pause];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[self copySoundFileURL] error:nil];
[player play];
```

(these are ofcourse examples)

Basically my question is if anyone knows a way to do either of these:

1. Play a file that is open in the recorder.
2. Stop the recorder, play the file and then resume recording on the same file (not losing the previously recorded stuff).

Any information/thoughts are welcome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could find to fix this is by merging 2 wav files. some more information on this is found in another one of my questions: [NSURL returns Invalid Summary when merging WAV files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535380/nsurl-returns-invalid-summary-when-merging-wav-files) . This is not 100% correct (hence the question) but it's a start for people that want some information about this.