# AVAudioPlayer refuses to play modified wav file

Tags: objective-c, c, avaudioplayer, wav

The first time i call this method `file1` will be nil and `file2` will be returned. When this hapens the file will play normally (so the calling of this method should be fine). But when i call it for the second time it will return an `NSURL` which the AVAudioPlayer does not play. My guess is I have missed something in the header. In the debugging mode i have seen that the `totalLength` is exactly as long as the data's length.

```
+(NSURL *)mergeFile1:(NSURL *)file1 withFile2:(NSURL *)file2 {
    if(file1 == nil) {
        return [file2 copy];
    }

    NSData * wav1Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file1];
    NSData * wav2Data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file2];

    int wav1DataSize = [wav1Data length] - 46;  
    int wav2DataSize = [wav2Data length] - 46;

    if (wav1DataSize <= 0 ||  wav2DataSize <= 0) {
        return nil;
    }   

    NSMutableData * soundFileData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:[wav1Data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 46)]];
    [soundFileData appendData:[wav1Data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(46, wav1DataSize)]];
    [soundFileData appendData:[wav2Data subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(46, wav2DataSize)]];

    unsigned int totalLength = [soundFileData length];

    NSLog(@"Calculated: %d - Real: %d", totalLength, [soundFileData length]);

    [soundFileData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 4)
                             withBytes:&(UInt32){NSSwapHostIntToLittle(totalLength-8)}];
    [soundFileData replaceBytesInRange:NSMakeRange(42, 4)
                             withBytes:&(UInt32){NSSwapHostIntToLittle(totalLength)}];

    [soundFileData writeToURL:file1 atomically:YES];

    return [file1 copy];
}
```

If anyone sees something that can be of help it would be much appreciated! 
Any questions will be answered asap.

**EDIT**

I know there are 2 sorts of wav headers: 44 bytes or 46 bytes. I have tried both.

**EDIT**

I have looked at the [Audio File Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html) which contains a lot of nice stuff i might want to use, but i can't figure out how to use all this. I'm not really known with c. Hope anyone could help me out with this.

**EDIT**

An example of a merged wav file is found here: [7--443522512](http://www.2shared.com/audio/rtfbVJO7/7--443522512.html)

Comment: Repost? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535380/nsurl-returns-invalid-summary-when-merging-wav-files/8569393

Comment: Have you tried save the wav to a file when running in the simulator and then tried to play it in some other player?

Comment: @MattiasWadman Its not a repost as with that one i tried to find a way to get rid of a memory problem, but with this one that is all fixed and i'm trying to get the wav to play. Seems the same, is different.
I have not tried that, will try that now.

Comment: Nope, it will not let me play in a music player either. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Then inspect the wav file with a hex editor, run `file file.wav` in a terminal etc and try to spot any errors. If you dont find anything, post an example of a merged wav file that people can help you inspect.

Comment: Does anyone know what i can do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your WAV file includes a broken `FLLR` chunk before the `data` chunk, or at least VLC thinks the `FLLR` chunk is over 2GB large so it tries to skip to the next chunk which is beyond the file end.

Maybe you should try to create WAV files without `FLLR` chunk before merging, the `kAudioFileFlags_DontPageAlignAudioData` seams to make Audio File Services skip it.

Another option is to extract the `data` chunks and write a new wav file, a did a proof of concept implementation here: https://gist.github.com/1555889

Comment: Do you have any info on how to do this (link or code), would be much appriciated!

Comment: From where do you get the wav-files? do you create them with the audio file service API?

Comment: I record them with the AVAudioRecorder (within the same app).

Comment: Awesome!! that code works like a charm. I modified to copy the second file to the first file when the first is empty and now it works perfectly!! Thanks so much ^_^

Comment: Nice! what kind of app are you developing?

Comment: It's an app to record, play sound and send it to a webserver which will use some speech to text software and make a report from it and send it to the customer ^_^