# After wav files are merged the NSURL is nil

Tags: objective-c, nsurl, null

Ok so I have this method (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8535380/nsurl-returns-invalid-summary-when-merging-wav-files)). It appends 2 wav files together to play them afterwards. The method gets called like this:

```
if(soundFileURL != nil) {
    NSURL *tempURL = [WavUtils mergeFile1:finalSoundFileURL withFile2:soundFileURL];

    if(tempURL != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Wav files have been merged: %@", [tempURL absoluteString]);
        finalSoundFileURL = [tempURL retain];
        [soundFileURL release];
        soundFileURL = nil;
        [recorder release];
        recorder = nil;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Wav files could not be merged.");
    }
}
```

The retain in `finalSoundFileURL = [tempURL retain];` has been replaced with many other things than retain but it doesn't work at all. When the merging is done i check what the file contains with this:

```
NSLog(@"Calculated: %d - Real: %d", totalLength, [soundFileData length]);
NSLog(@"From file: %d", [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:file1] length]);
```

This shows the following in the log:

```
2012-01-02 18:20:28.549 App[2186:207] Calculated: 72146 - Real: 72146
2012-01-02 18:20:28.549 App[2186:207] From file: 72146
```

So the file is filled, the NSURL is filled and points to the correct file. But when i try to send this file to the server i check again with this:

```
NSLog(@"Adding file: %@ with length: %d", [finalSoundFileURL absoluteString], [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:finalSoundFileURL] length]);
```

But this returns the following:

```
2012-01-02 18:22:38.980 App[2186:207] Adding file: (null) with length: 0
```

This leads me to beleve it's an autorelease problem, but I can't find it! If anyone has any idea where it could be, please tell me.

Regards

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code provided, and it's not an autorelease problem, since the references aren't zeroed when something is dealloc'ed, you'd get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS instead of a zero pointer.

Comment: Post the code related to your upload to the server.

Comment: @joerick In that case i wonder why it gets nulled for no reason. I don't set it to nil. 
The code up here is what tells me (the second check) that it is empty BEFORE being added to the httprequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not posting this sooner but the problem was a bad release/autorelease call on the variable before it was sent to the method described in the question. I found it by following the variable from start to end and check what it's doing and what happens to it.